# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::students()

Tags: database, laravel, relationships

I'm trying to attach a certain student to a certain subject with this code.[This is the part of the controller which is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWJO1.png).

Here I also attach the Models:
[Model1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnLNu.png)
[Model2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVFxa.png)

Comment: Please post the minimum amount of code necessary to demonstrate your issue instead of posting images of code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors Also its generally a good idea to include the problem statement in the question itself, even if it is already in the title.

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ˋget()ˋ before ˋstudents()ˋ

```
$subject = Subject::where('id', $id)->get();
$subject->students()...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the subject first:

```php
Subject::find($id)->students()->attach($student_id);
```